# User Information List issue

Tags: user-profile, user-information-list

I have an unusual problem with User Information List in my main site collection. After unknown circumstances, we lost quite a few users from that list (their profiles still exist). Moreover in .../sites/ collection, list is workin properly.

What're the consequences? In  collection i can "use" that user, e.g. add him to permissions list or pick in peoplepicker. However in my main site collection, there's no such user and i cant change or use anything related to that user.

Answer (score 0):

Each site collection has it's own user information list, so this isn't out of the ordinary for the two lists to contain different data.

Are you sure the user was "lost"? It's more likely that the user was never created in the other site collection.

The first time a user logs in to a site collection, that user is added to the user information list. Until then they will not appear in the list.

You can "force" the addition of a user to the user information list by calling `SPWeb.EnsureUser()` on one of the webs in the site collection. If the user does not exist, they will be added to the user information list during this method call.

See [SPWeb.EnsureUser Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx)